# Is the boundary of this open set compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces. Assume that for $x\in X$ and open subset $U\subseteq X$ containing $x$, there exists an open subset $N$ in $X\times Y$ such that $\partial N$ is compact and $N\subseteq U\times Y$ ($\partial N$ is the boundary of $N$). Now, my question is:

Is $\partial \pi_{1}(N)$ compact where $\pi_{1}$ is the projection onto Y? I deduce that if Y be compact, then the problem is fixed. How about in general?

Comment: Do you want to assume that $N$ and $U$ are non-empty?

Comment: @Jakobian surely empty set is trivially compact

Comment: What's the point of introducing $x$ and then not using it? It's just to say that $U$ is non-empty?

Answer (score -1):

in general no.

take the unit ball in Hilbert space $l^2$, space of bounded sequences.

take the boundary to be the unit sphere:

$(x\in l^2; ||x||=1)$
take sequence $\{x_n\}$ of zeros and 1 in the nth place.
then for every $n,m$, $||x_n-x_m||=\sqrt{2}$.

hence it is not cauchy and has no convergent subsequece.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is a counter-example of

Comment: The question was "is the boundary of an open set compact?".

Comment: The unit ball without boundary in $l^2$ is open.

Comment: The boundary is the unit sphere which is closed, bounded and as i have shown not compact.

Comment: The question isn't "is the boundary of an open set compact", it's "does the projection of an open set with compact boundary have compact boundary"